# syslog-ng does not include severity in its lines

Tags: logs, embedded, syslog-ng

I'm trying to configure syslog-ng in an embedded distro.

I added the syslog-ng package.

I was expecting the /var/log/ files to include their log severity / log level, but it isn't to.

Any way to configure syslog-ng to add the severity to each line?

Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 5):

By default, `file()` destinations output old [BSD-formatted](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3164) messages without the severity field.

You can use the `syslog-protocol` flag to produce a [IETF-syslog](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424) output with the severity field included:

```
destination d_test{ file("/tmp/test" flags("syslog-protocol")); };
```

Alternatively, you can create your own custom template:

```
destination d_test {
  file("/tmp/test"
    template("$ISODATE $HOST ${FACILITY}(${FACILITY_NUM}) ${SEVERITY}(${SEVERITY_NUM}) $MSGHDR$MSG\n")
  );
};
```